# Como capturar informações de um processo 64 bits que esta em execução?

Tags: c#, .net, processo, runtime, x64

Bem, necessito de ajuda para capturar as informações de um processo que esta em execução. Consigo realizar tal tarefa acessando o `mainmodule` dos processos 32-bits, porém, não consigo fazer o mesmo com os processos 64-bits. Não sei se o motivo é eu estar tentando acessar tais informações por uma aplicação 32-bits.
Consigo acessar o `mainmodule` dos processos 64-bits, porém, o retorno é nulo.

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            //Capturando a descrição de um processo em execução
            string nomeProd = clsProcess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription.ToString();
        }
```

Como dito, funciona perfeitamente em um computador 32-bits, já que o mesmo não contém programas 64-bits. Porém, estou desenvolvendo a aplicação para os dois tipos(32 e 64), e necessito de ajuda para capturar as informações de um processo em 64-bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal gerar uma aplicação 64 bits e ser feliz assim? Essa é a solução mais adequada.

Se ainda quiser continuar no 32 bits e só não quer que o erro pare a aplicação, basta capturar a exceção `Win32Exception`. Pegará os processos 32 bits e ignorará os 64 bits.

Em geral é preciso privilégio de administrador para executar isso. Ainda assim não terá acesso a todos os processos, isso é normal, por isso capturar esta exceção é importante.

Há uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991822/221800) que usa a API do Windows de forma direta e pode ajudar. Não sei se te ajuda.

Há uma [solução no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234529/221800) escrita em VB.NET usando o `System.Management` que pode ajudar também.

Espero que isto pelo menos dê uma caminho.

Comment: É...passei a aplicação pra 64 bites. Agora tenho uma 32 e uma 64 mas, depois que eu passei pra 64 bites, ocorreu um erro de descrição "A single valid machine type compatible with the input type library must be specified".  File - TlbImp.
Sabe o que pode ser? A aplicação roda normalmente, pois já arrumei as dlls e tudo. Mas, esse erro permanece.

Comment: @Wesley.rain não sei, veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2450509/221800

Answer (score 0):

Se sua aplicação é escrita em código gerenciado, ela pode ser compilada para "Any CPU", assim ela vai se comportar de acordo om o sistema operacional em execução.
Você vai obter as informações de processos rodando em 32 e 64 bits.